# django flatten dictionaries in ajax get / post

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to send simple ajax request to django via get/post (doesn't matter) and it seems like django flattens the dictionary when parsing the request.

With example:

What I send to django in ajax (via jquery):

```
{'payload':{'website':'localhost.com'}}
```

What I get in request.post on django side:

```
{u'payload[website]': [u'localhost.com']}
```

Why?

thanks,

EDIT:
added jquery call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: full_url,
    data: {'payload': {'website': 'localhost.com'}},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true,
    timeout: 5000,
});
```

Comment: it's actually jquery that has flattened the dictionary. you can't send a "dictionary" over ajax, only plain text. you can encode objects into text as json, or form data (what seems to have happened here, by default) or xml or anything

Comment: what content-type are you sending to the django server? It should be set to : 'application/json'

Comment: @jumojer both "json" and "application/json" return the same result.

Comment: @Anentropic I send data as json so jquery should do JSON.stringify internally. I also tried sending as plaintext and do the stringify myself, got slightly different result: {u'{"payload":{"website":"localhost.com"}}': [u'']}

Comment: `contentType` should either be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Brandon thanks, but both options do the same. :/

Comment: I would remove the option entirely, as the default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

What content-type are you sending to the django server? 
It should be set to : 'application/json' so the server knows it is receiving json. 
Also, try to retrieve the data with request.data instead of data.post. 
You should then be able to do the following:

```
if (request.data):
   payload = request.data['payload']
```

Quick note, if thats all you are passing to the server i would remove one level and only send the inner dictionnary like so :

```
{'website':'localhost.com'}
```

and then retrieve it with

```
request.data['website']
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. content type is already 'application/json' :/  added the ajax call to the original question.